# Show that $\frac\pi2 \int_0^\pi\;\mathrm{e}^{\sin x}\;\mathrm{d}x = \int_0^\pi x\mathrm{e}^{\sin x}\;\mathrm{d}x $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

> Prove that $$\dfrac\pi2 \int\limits_0^\pi \mathrm{e}^{\sin x}\;\mathrm{d}x = \int\limits_0^\pi x\mathrm{e}^{\sin x}\;\mathrm{d}x \;.$$

I have found that $\int\limits_0^\pi \mathrm{e}^{\sin x}\;\mathrm{d}x$ is equal to  $\pi\left(L_0(1) + I_0(1)\right)$.

Comment: A tip: it could be helpful to learn [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) formatting.

Answer (score 6):

Let's play with the right hand side a little:
$$\begin{align} \int_0^\pi x e^{\sin x} dx &= -\int_\pi^0(\pi-t)e^{\sin(\pi-t)}dt
\\
&= \int_0^\pi (\pi-t)e^{\sin(\pi - t)} dt \\
&= \pi \int_0^\pi e^{\sin t} dt -\int_0^\pi te^{\sin t} dt \\
2\int_0^\pi te^{\sin t} dt &= \pi \int_0^\pi e^{\sin t} dt
\end{align}$$
From here, your result easily follows.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain me the last two steps ? @B.Metha

Comment: In the penultimate step, I split up the integral into two parts, and used $\sin(\pi-t) = \sin(t)$

Comment: On the penultimate line, notice that the last integral is exactly the same thing as on the right hand side, so you can add it on

Comment: Thanks a lot! @B.Mehta